# Get Wordpress sidebar from another Wordpress blog?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a plugin that will pull a sidebar from one Wordpress blog and place it in the sidebar of another blog. I know to write a plugin, but actually don't know where to start with this idea.

Comment: So you want to pull the sidebar from one blog, over to another blog? And you wrote a plugin? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I want to do that with a plugin,stil didnt wrote a plugin,I'm asking for someone to help me a little bit with this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe he's saying that he wants to write a plugin to be able to retrieve a sidebar from another website and display it (possibly as a widget?). If that is not the question then I apologize; otherwise, I'll take a shot at answering.

The first thing I would recommend would be to view the code of just about any other widget plugin to make sure that a plugin (and not just some JavaScript) is really what you want.

Assuming you want the plugin, [check out this resource for some basics](http://valums.com/create-wordpress-widget/). Also, you'll need the retrieval code which will either be ["screen-scraping" in PHP](http://www.developertutorials.com/php/easy-screen-scraping-in-php-simple-html-dom-library-simplehtmldom-398/) or [AJAX partial page loading with JavaScript](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

I hope any or all of this helps you get where you're going.

Comment: Yes that is what i want to do,I know to write plugins and widgets,I'll study Easy Screen Scraping,think that this will solve my problem,but I was hoping that there is some wordpress function,that will just list all widget from sidebar of my another blog.Something like thit,access to database on other blog,list all widgets from other blog.
Sorry on my bad English :( and all that with a plugin(widget).